# Scala. Список футур. Выполнение шаг за шагом

Tags: scala, future

Хола, коллеги!
У меня есть список некоторых сущностей. Они могут быть вложены друг в друга. Например:

```
case class Entity(id: Long, parentId: Long)

val list = List(
    Entity(1,0),
    Entity(2,1),
    Entity(3,2),
    Entity(4,1),
    Entity(5,0)
)
```

Мне нужно добавить их в БД. Мой сервис:

```
val listOfFutures = list map createEntity // createEntity - мой метод,
                                          // который добавляет сущность в БД.
                                          // Возвращает Future[Entity]
Future.sequence( listOfFutures ) map { _ => println("Ok!") }
```

Проблема в constraints(Как их по-русски назвать?). Получаю ошибку:

> Create failed. No such parent 1 entity exists.

Я думаю, что проблема в том, что метод createEntity выполняется параллельно. Как заставить этот код выполняться последовательно, сущность за сущностью?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Future считается монадой, так как у неё есть последовательный `flatMap`:

```
list.foldLeft(Future.successful(()))(( prevF, entity) =>
  prevF
    .flatMap( _ => createEntity(entity))
    .map( _ => ())
)
```

Аналогичный код, используя for-comprehension:

```
list.foldLeft(Future.successful(()))(( prevF, entity) =>
  for {
    _ <- prevF
    _ <- createEntity(entity)
  } yield ()
)
```

---

Объяснение:

```
val entity = Entity(0, 1)
createEntity(entity).map( _ => println("Ok!"))
```

Метод `map` запоминает полученную функцию и выполняет её **после** того как получит успешный результат `Future`.

Meтод `flatMap` работает также, только ожидает что полученная функция тоже  будет возвращать `Future`.

```
createEntity(entityOne).flatMap( _ => createEntity(entityTwo))
```

Таким образом мы соединяем две `Future` последовательно, т.е. вторая вызовется только после успешного выполнения первой.

Отсюда очевидно что мы можем выстраивать длинные **последовательные** цепочки.

```
createEntity(entityOne)
    .flatMap( _ => createEntity(entityTwo))
    .flatMap( _ => createEntity(entityThree))
    .flatMap( _ => createEntity(entityFour))
```

А результатом будет новая `Future`.
Ок, а как поступить если у нас есть список `Future`?  Так же как мы бы поступили бы например с числами.

```
val listNumbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val zeroNumber = 0
def joinNumbers(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b

listNumbers.foldLeft(zeroNumber)(joinNumbers)
```

Почему `foldLeft`, а не `map`? Потому что прибавляем по очереди, и нам нужна сумма предыдущих чисел.
Зачем нужен `zeroNumber`? Ну а вдруг список пустой - вернем 0.

Теперь с Future:

```
val listEntities: List[Entity] = ???

val zeroFuture = Future.successful(())
def joinFuture(prevF: Future[Unit], entity: Entity): Future[Unit] =
    prevF
     .flatMap(_ => createEntity(entity)) //  тут вторая Future
     .map( _ => ())

listEntities.foldLeft(zeroFuture)(joinFuture)
```

Следующий `createEntity` выполняется **после** предыдущих.
Зачем нужен `zeroFuture` -  ну а вдруг список пустой.

---

**UPD:**

Попробую подробней расписать почему `foldLeft`, а не `map`.
Сначала взглянем на `map`:

```
val listOfFutures = list.map( entity => createEntity(entity))
```

`map` просто проходит по листу и вызывает создание Энтити. Он не ждёт пока создание завершится, он просто создаёт новую `Future` и идёт дальше к следующему элементу листа.

Т.е. на каждой итерации нам нужно "нечто" что будет знать о том что на предыдущем шаге Энтити создался:

```
val listOfFutures = list.map( entity =>
    val prevEntityWasCreated = ??? // что-то, что знает о предыдущем Энтити

    // flatMap заставляет выполнятся ПОСЛЕ
    prevEntityWasCreated.flatMap(_ => createEntity(entity))
)
```

Т.е. проходимся по списку и на каждом этапе ждем пока завершиться предыдущий. Что-то подобное нам надо, верно?

Точнее такое:

```
val listOfFutures = list.map( (prevEntityWasCreated, entity) =>

    prevEntityWasCreated.flatMap(_ => createEntity(entity))
)
```

Супер. Второй энтити ждет когда создастся первый, третий ждёт когда создастся второй. А чего ждёт первый? Надо создать пустую `Future` специально для первой этнити:

```
val zeroFuture = Future.successful(())
val listOfFutures = list.map(zeroFuture)( (prevEntityWasCreated, entity) =>

    prevEntityWasCreated.flatMap(_ => createEntity(entity))
)
```

Всё отлично, только тип не совпадает:

```
val zeroFuture: Future[Unit] = Future.successful(())
val foo: Future[Entity] = prevEntityWasCreated.flatMap(_ => createEntity(entity))
```

Просто добавим `map` и изменим тип на одинаковый

```
val zeroFuture: Future[Unit] = Future.successful(())
val foo: Future[Unit] = prevEntityWasCreated.flatMap(_ => createEntity(entity)).map( _ => ())
```

Последнии штрих - переименовать новую функцию в `foldLeft`.

```
list.foldLeft(Future.successful(()))(( prevF, entity) =>

  val foo: Future[Unit] =
      prevF
        .flatMap( _ => createEntity(entity))
        .map( _ => ())
  // возвращаем Future для следующего элемента
  foo
)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, что происходит в этом коде, и почему нельзя без `fold` обойтись?

Comment: @Oleg,
Начал, но понял что расписывать можно долго, уточни что именно тебе не понятно: как работает `foldLeft` у листа, как работает `flatMap` или `map` у фьючи, что такое `Future.successful`, зачем нужен "лишний" `map`, что дают пустые скобки?

Comment: Спасибо за классный ответ. Поставил бы еще плюсов, еслиб мог. Мне не до конца понятно, зачем нужен "лишний" `fold`, раз `flatMap` итак выполняет все операции последовательно? Почему нельзя просто написать `for { e <- list; _ <- createEntity(e); } yield ()`

Comment: Если коротко, то в for-comprehension можно использовать что-то одно за раз - либо `List`, либо `Future`. В комментах расписать не удобно, но тебе надо взглянуть на то как это выглядит без сахара. Выглядит как `flatMap`. А `flatMap` у листа ждет `List`, `flatMap` у фьючи ждёт `Future`.

Comment: Я понял вроде. Благодарю за разъяснение.

Comment: Добавил пункт касательно почему  `foldLeft`.

Comment: Спасибо. Целый урок по футурам получился)

Comment: Небольшое замечание: `scala.concurrent.Future` монадой, формально, не является - он запускается сразу же после создания, что в ряде случаев приводит к нарушению монадических тождеств в результате гонки. Однако, flatMap у него всё же есть, и на корректность примера это не влияет. Различие важно только в чистом ФП для разграничения побочных эффектов. В этом случае можно использовать `Task` из scalaz-concurrent, запускающийся по требованию.